# Symfony twig template link to changed prefix

Tags: php, symfony, routes

Is there any way in Symfony2 to put the link(in the twig template), which would change the `prefix` set in the `app/config/routing.yml`? For eample, here's my `app/config/routing.yml` file:

```
    acme_main:
    resource: "@AcmeMainBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /{_locale}/
    requirements: 
        _locale: |en|fr|de
```

And I want to insert 3 links which are supposed to change the locale(it's about the translation, but it doesn't matter, let's focus on the `prefix` in general). How would I do that? I tried something like this

```
<a href="{{ path('route_x') }}"><img src="{{ asset('path/path/path/some_flag.jpg') }}"></a>
```

Where `route_x` is route defined in the `routing.yml` of the specific bundle, but I couldn't figure it out to work. Form this level `prefix` is untouchable. Is there any way or am I doing it wrong? Please help! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly set `_locale` in the `path` function:

```
{{ path('route_x', {_locale: ''}) }}
```

And set it to your default value for `_locale` then it will not appear in the generated URL.